# how i can browse a JSON object

Tags: php, json

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( 
                [0] => IMG_20161025_164836_461.jpg 
                [1] => IMG_20161025_164844_915.jpg ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
                [0] => IMG_20161025_164851_516.jpg 
                [1] => IMG_20161025_164908_240.jpg ) 
        [2] => Array ( 
                [0] => IMG_20161025_164917_414.jpg 
                [1] => IMG_20161025_164929_589.jpg ) 
        )
```

how i can browse a JSON object

Comment: have you even *tried* anything yet? for example reading [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: Where's the json object?

Comment: @RiggsFolly this is already decoded

Comment: What does *browse* mean?

Comment: $brandings=json_decode($brandings); // for decoding the json element after that i make   foreach($brandings as $element){
    echo $element[0];
    echo $element[1];
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use foreach

```
foreach($arr as $element){
    echo $element[0];
    echo $element[1];
}
```

Comment: @raafetdhaouadi Happy to help